# Transpose table for multiple rows

Tags: sql, pivot

I need to transpose table either is SQL or Excel.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and a crosstab or pivot is highly product specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: [Previous crosstab/pivot questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%sql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)